# How set an items value when phone reaches a specific location?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 22.2 to develop a PWA app which should work on Android phones. It's a game for kids. The code used is pure JavaScript. The game is like a race. There's a circular place. The race starts with the kid standing on a point of a 10 meters horizontal line which represents the starting line of the race. The kid has it's phone on him with Location service switched on. The kid starts running. When the kid reaches the starting line again **on any point of the 10 meters wide**, it means they passed one round. The app then should assign the round number to the dedicated item `round_no` each time the kid passes the starting line from any point of the 10 meters wide.
Below, is the code I've tried. I believe it's theoretically true. But the problem is it does not set the value of the round_no item when the kid passes the line. Which means it never reach the same longitude again.
I am assuming that the whole 10 meters line is on the same longitude because it's horizontal.
One thing I noticed is that the new location is not updated continuously. For example, if longitude = 31.1234**1**, I assume, when I move, it should change to 31.1234**2** then 31.1234**3** - notice the last number. But what happens is that 31.1234**1** could change 31.1234**9** directly. I think that could be the reason that new location rarely equals the starting line's location.

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
  document.getElementById("starting_long").innerHTML =
    position.coords.longitude;
});

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
  document.getElementById("current_location").innerHTML =
    position.coords.longitude;

  if (
    position.coords.longitude ==
    document.getElementById("starting_long").innerHTML
  ) {
    document.getElementById("round_no").innerHTML =
      Number(document.getElementById("round_no").innerHTML) + 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="round_no">Round no.:</label>
<input id="round_no">
<br><br>
<label for="starting_long">Starting long:</label>
<input id="starting_long">
<br><br>
<label for="current_location">Current Location:</label>
<input id="current_location">
```

Comment: You might be expecting too much in the way of gps accuracy.  From my limited research it looks accurate to about 5m in perfect conditions, which is a distance greater than 0.00001 of a degree of longitude.  [ref for distances at the equator](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/approx_equivalents.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure if the accuracy would matter because it would affect all values. Meaning,  the starting line's longitude would be more or less the actual value by 5 meters, and so all the next values. But the problem is that the new values are not incremented by .00001.